# MySql filling the rest of the data after I have selected a distinct value

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

ive done this to pull the distinct data

```
INSERT INTO `goac`.`customer`
( CUST_ID)
SELECT DISTINCT CUST_ID
FROM ods_customer
```

but I would like to bring the rest of the data with it and have it fill out the table.

[image: distinct values with no other values]

I am pulling data from 2 tables for this one.

Comment: do you want to add all of the columns values from the `select` statement?

Comment: I am getting a problem where If I  don't set it to where the id is distinct I cannot enter any other data because of duplicate primary. For this one, I need to pull from 2 different tables for the information.

Comment: I need to pull the rest of the information after doing a distinct on the Id column.

Answer (score 0):

According to your info above. I guess...

Try to add more column in insert statement

`INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, value3...);`

Maybe like

`` INSERT INTO `goac`.`customer` ( CUST_ID, CUST_NM, CUST_INCOME_AM, CUST_STREET_AD...) SELECT DISTINCT CUST_ID FROM ods_customer ``